# Remount roofts read-only after boot up

Tags: linux, debian

I looking for the best way to remount server rootfs after complete boot when all system services are started and running. Remount should be preformed only when all services was successfully started and none of them reports any error (exit code > 0). I use systemd as init service, but not sure if remounting by startup script is the best way to achieve this task.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to do this? Many of your running services will be very unhappy that they can't write to their tmp files (etc) any more.

Comment: I have separate partitions for /var and /tmp folders, I been running with read-only rootfs for almost a year without any unexpected problems. My current configuration mounts rootfs as read-only in fstab file, which cause problems with services like readahead or cleanups scripts.

Comment: Gotcha.  Sounds like an interesting configuration.

Comment: And i use read-only rootfs for ensure that all my machines are equal - I don't want any service to write any changes anywhere except var and tmp directories, I have Puppet for making these changes.

Comment: ...but obviously puppet won't be able to make changes to a read-only filesystem :)  Just being pernickety, I'm sure you've thought of that.

Comment: Puppet agent are executed by cron, which remounts rootfs read-write before executing agent sync and closes it again after sync completed :)

Comment: Your config makes my head spin ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a debian box in front of me, but I believe this can be accomplished this way:

1. Create a custom service script in `/etc/init.d/` called something like `remountroot` or something like that.

   - The 'start' command probably remounts root as r/o.
   - The 'stop' command probably remounts root as r/w.
   - The 'status' command probably just spits out the mount-state of root, useful for scripting.
2. In that custom script include: `# Required-Start: $all` in the LSB header to make it run last.

I'm not quite sure how best to handle stop-service ordering so that root becomes writable as the system is shutting down.